# how to display images from web in ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I need to make app that will work like image gallery: I should use view pager and when user swipe left or right, app should load image from web URL. Currently I have an array which contains images from drawable folder. I want to know a way to load images from web and display it in ViewPager.

This is my Activity class.

```
public class FullImageActivity2 extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_image_activity2);

        //Selected image id
        Integer[] newArray={R.drawable.digitallovesaktid,R.drawable.abcd,R.drawable.blue};


        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, newArray);
        List<ImageView> images = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < imageAdapter.getCount(); i1++) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

            imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[i1]);

            images.add(imageView);
        }

        // Finally create the adapter
        ImagePagerAdapter imagePagerAdapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(images);
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(imagePagerAdapter);


    }
}
```

This is my BaseAdapter class

```
        public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;


    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {};


    public ImageAdapter(Context c, Integer[] mThumbIds2){
        mContext = c;
        this.mThumbIds=mThumbIds2;
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
        //imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.edit_border);
        imageView.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);

        return imageView;
    }
}
```

This is my pager adapter class

```
public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private List<ImageView> images;

    public ImagePagerAdapter(List<ImageView> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = images.get(position);
        container.addView(imageView);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView(images.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return view == o;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Picasso library to load images from url. Visit Link http://square.github.io/picasso/